# Unable to add Oracle Cloud private key to Putty

Tags: ssh, putty

I created a VM instance in Oracle Cloud, I downloaded private and public keys locally.

When want to import in Putty the private key downloaded, I got:

[image]

I know but I didn't touch private key file and I followed their steps but those are old steps.

The private key look like:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
MIIEvgIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAASCBKgwggSkAgEAAoIBAQDgeq6QBHOc3t0W
...
...
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

How to solve it ?

PS:

I tried with Conversion > Import key:

[image]

And I got same error message:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The "Load" button only accepts PuTTY's native .PPK format. But your key is in OpenSSH (PKCS#8) format, so you'll need to use the *Conversions → Import key* menu option to load it.

Comment: I used Conversions and I got same error